# jQuery Validate: Override pre-existing error labels

Tags: jquery, validation

Been breaking my head with the documentation for hours!

Side:
http://adam-sites-for-clients.info/set-up/

Plugin:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/

I created error labels to be hidden and shown on validation, based on the reference guide for this plugin here:
docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference#Error_message_display

It says:
"When provided in the markup, they are shown and hidden accordingly, otherwise created on demand."

I already provided them in markup, so why are they still being created? And why my existing ones don't toggle?

Thanks!

PS. That's the input:

```
<input id="name" class="textbox required" type="text" name="name" />
```

And the error label:

```
<label class="error" for="name">*נא להזין שם</label>
```

Comment: Added an example of input and error label or ref!

Comment: Any takers? Need something more from me to tackle this?

Comment: Can you include your javascript? Perhaps a mocked up jsfiddle?